# Functional approach to transform an array of objects into a hierarchical structure with aggregates

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a functional solution to map this object into a hierarchical structure and group by practice, subjectarea, and asset so that this object:

```
var data = {
  "research": [
    { "practice": "Talent Management", "id": "20992", "title": "Creating a Culture of Leadership", "subjectArea": "Talent Strategy" },
    { "practice": "Talent Management", "id": "20993", "title": "Talent Economics", "subjectArea": "Talent Strategy" },
    { "practice": "Talent Management", "id": "20990", "title": "Finding the Right Talent", "subjectArea": "Recruiting" },
    {  "practice": "Human Resources", "id": "20994", "title": "Tips from the Front", "subjectArea": "HR Training" },
    { "practice": "Human Resources", "id": "20995", "title": "Reward Programs", "subjectArea": "Employee Engagement" },
  ]
}
```

gets transformed into this (count the number of items for a practice and add the subject areas for the practice as children, count the number of items for a subject area within the practice and add the asset (id and title) as children for the subject area):

```
{
  "name": "research",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Talent Management", "size": 3, "children": [
          {
            "name": "Talent Strategy", "size": 2, "children": [
              { "name": "Creating a Culture of Leadership", "id": "20992", "size": 1 },
              { "name": "Talent Economics", "id": "20993", "size": 1 }
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Recruiting", "size": 1, "children": [
              { "title": "Finding the Right Talent", "id": "20990", "size": 1 },
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Human Resources", "size": 2, "children": [
          {
            "name": "HR Training", "size": 1, "children": [
              { "name": "Tips from the Front", "id": "20994", "size": 1 },
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "Employee Engagement", "size": 1, "children": [
              { "name": "Reward Programs", "id": "20995", "size": 1 },
            ]
          }
        ]
      }, 
    ]  
}
```

I haven't been able to sort out the map and reduce combination to use to yield the correct result with counts, and appreciate any insight.

Comment: Why doesn't `research` have a `size` field?

Comment: Why do want to do this with `map` and `reduce`? Would you be able to do it without?

Comment: This isn't what SO is here for. We're here to answer questions about why code behaves how it does and other specific problems related to software engineering and programming. We're specifically not here to do your job/hobby for you. If you have a partial solution, paste it and ask us to help you understand it/debug it/fix it, but don't give us a spec for a function and expect a good response. Plus, there are, literally, billions of good answers to this question, which is what we call 'too broad'

Comment: I could do it without map or reduce, I guess nested for loops would be sufficient. I had asked for map or reduce to see how this might be accomplished, as Engineer Dollery points out, SO is used for understanding how code behaves, and in this particular case I'm trying to understand how it would be used in this example. But at the end of the day, I'm trying to see an actual working example of how to do this transformation - map, reduce, or regular loops. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be what SO is for (as per comments above), but in case anyone needs to transform an array of flat objects into a hierarchical structure that you can simply specify the nesting order, number of levels, and field names, here is a recursive function to do so - https://github.com/lance-p/configurable-transform-flat-array-to-nested. Hope it might be of help to others.